# Div floating right is pushing my centered table to the left. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```css
table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 220px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  Contact
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <table class="center">
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stuff</td>
      <td>More Stuff</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a website that has a scrolling menu in the center of the page, which is working fine. I want to add a `div`/aside to the right side of the menu for contact information and hours, but the div is pushing the top `table` element to the left and messing up alignment. I tried making it `inline`, but that did not fix it, and getting rid of the margins did not help either.

Comment: Give your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Did you try main div. with 3 divs inside. simply set the menu in the middle div. The right holds your contact and the third is a place holder. You can play with as you like. Please note that avoiding float is a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the margin-left and right to the menu element and add `width:fit-content;` to it like this:

```css
.menu.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:-moz-fit-content;
  width:fit-content;
}

table {
  width:100%;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 220px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
Contact
</div>



<div class="menu center">
<table>
<tr><th>Heading</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Stuff</td><td>More Stuff</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Depending on what you want, you might prefer this over `position:absolute` of the contact div, because the table will not overlap it when the window is too narrow to contain them both. And neither does it force the width of the table to a given size. On the other hand, this requires a very modern browser to work.

Comment: when more tables are added, this is the solution that works! I have a box on the left and right now and this keeps everything even. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apply a percentage width your table, and also a percentage left-margin that fits this width (and no right margin). Also, add `colspan="2"` to the (only) `th` , and center the contents of the `th` and `td` elements:

```css
table.center {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 220px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  Contact
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <table class="center">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stuff</td>
      <td>More Stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this, and this works at first, but when I add more tables under the center one the div to the right starts pushing the top table to the left, moving it all out of line.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your "right" div is floating and has "display: inline". One possible solution (among several others) is to position your "right" div absolutely inside a container. See the suggestion.

```css
table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 220px;
}

.right-container {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 width: 60px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

.right {
  display: relative;
  right: -60px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-container">
<div class="right">
  Contact
</div>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <table class="center">
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stuff</td>
      <td>More Stuff</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this works at first, but when more center tables are added it pulls the top table to the right.